# Ember complex property bindings

Tags: ember.js, momentjs

I am using quite complex property bindings to be able to change either day, month or year of a user's birthdate. Having an attr `birthDate` of type `date` on a user and three properties for each piece of the date.
I am using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to simplify date manipulations.

By trying the [reduced showcase on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YBm36/5/) you'll see that if you change year or day, the month is always increased by 1. I can't say what is happening. Just this: when setting the new date, the value is correct and gets changed later. Is there an issue with ember-data `date` attributes and some formating?

Again: [here's the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YBm36/5/) - written in [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked at your code and it looked like it should be working fine, the more I stepped through it the more I got annoyed that I couldn't spot the problem ... turns out it's the .month() method from Moment.js ... [from the docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/month/):

"Mutates the original moment by changing the month. Accepts numbers from 0 to 11"

Pretty dumb huh? In any case change your setMonth to subtract 1 from the value when you use .month()

```
setMonth: (property, value) ->
  @set property, moment(@get(property)).month(value-1).format()
  return value
```

Comment: Wow - what the f***. That rather feels like a bug in moment.js, but you're right - it is documented like that and it works :) Thanks for your effort!